# Realm shared table size

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

If I share a table on Realm Object Server between all users. If this table is very big. Is it   Going to take lot of space on the device or Realm has a kind of caching rolling system?

Comment: Define very big

Comment: Ok, how do you manage shared data between users?

Comment: Have you got any example to share a Realm ROS for all users R/W?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users will all end up with the same content on their devices.
The Realm Object Server will download the entire table content to all users that share a given Realm. There is no caching or rolling system.

Comment: Hi guy, I have you got an example of how to share a realm ROS between all users?